# I want to know about App Engine clearly

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm creating a moble application. When start the app, it has to download a file in server to create a data.
And I use App Engine to store my file.
What kind of the fee I have to pay.

Note: I only store my file and every my user have to download this file when stating the app.
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fees not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your mobile app will be Android based, then the [Java introduction to AppEngine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction) is a good starting point. You have a lot to learn, but the good news is that moderate usage is free.

Comment: Thank you Berends. When I have a lot user to download that file. It's still free ?

Comment: Up to 1 gigabyte per day is free according to [AppEngine Quotas](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests).  After that downloads cost US $0.12 per gigabyte according to [AppEngine Pricing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing).  Sorry about the downvotes others are giving, StackOverflow has rules about questions not being too general, but also aims to be friendly to beginners.  Tough choices.  Downvoters should add constructive comments.